# Efficient algorithm for finding number of almost sorted intervals

Tags: python, algorithm

In a problem, I have to find the number of consecutive sub sequences of an array which have the following conditions satisfied(They are called almost sorted intervals)

1. The first number in the sequence is the smallest.
2. The last number is the largest.

I wrote the following code, Which is giving me Time Limit Exceeded error. How can I optimize the algorithm and my code.

```
import sys


def ans(values):  

total=0;
small=[]    # Taking a array which contains the smallest till that index
svar1,lvar2=values[0],values[0]

for i in range(len(values)):
    if svar1<values[i]:
        small.append(svar1)
    elif svar1>=values[i]:   
        svar1=values[i]
        small.append(svar1)

for i in range(len(values)):   # for each value
    k=i
    highest=values[i]          # we consider the highest 
    lowest=values[i]           # we consider the lowest
    flag=0
    while k>=0:                # iterating back
        if values[k]>highest: #if we encounter an element greater than the last element 
            break
        if lowest>=values[k]:  #I try to maintain the lowest if I encounter one.
            total+=1             # counting for the answer
            lowest=values[k]     
        if values[k]==small[k]:  #I use that array and try to break the loop if I found that the smallest till then and the lowest are same.
            flag=1
        if k>0 and flag==1:
            if values[k-1]>small[k]:
                break

        k-=1
return total

if __name__=="__main__":
    y=input()
    values=map(int,sys.stdin.readline().split(" "))
    print ans(values)
```

Sorry for pasting the whole code. I hope it is understandable. Can I get a hint on how I can optimize it? The array length will be `1<=N<=10^6`

Example:

```
3 1 2 5 4 will give answer as 8
```

Comment: And have you profiled *this* code, to see where the time is being taken?

Comment: The algorithm is O(N^2) which is way too slow no matter how you "optimise" it. You need a better algorithm. (Profiling won't help)

Comment: what happens if there are two fives?

Comment: Googling "almost sorted interval" and looking around in the first search hit turns up an [O(nlog(n)) algorithm with explanation and code](https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/101may14/challenges/almost-sorted-interval/editorial) by the challenge's author.

Comment: Why a down vote? @user2357112 I did not want to implement the authors solution! "I wanted to try on my own".I indeed was trying to solve it.

Comment: @quasiverse I was trying to think if i could modify this to fit the time limit. That is why i took the list small to see if it provides any optimization.'

Comment: @PadraicCunningham when the input is [3,1,2,5,5] the answer is 11 and the sequences would be. [3] [1] [2] [5] [5] [1,2] [2,5] [5,5] [1,2,5] [2,5,5] [1,2,5,5]

Comment: so you don't add the second 5?can you explain how it is 11

Comment: The question asked for sequences for which the first element is smallest and last is the greatest. In the comment above i wrote those 11 sequences. are you asking me to trace the code? @PadraicCunningham

Comment: I presumed in you first example the answer was eight as the longest sequence is `1 2 5` which adds to 8, I don't see that logic in your second example

Comment: No, the question was to find number of sequences in the list which satisfy the conditions.

Comment: ok I get you now. So the middle numbers do not have to be sorted just the first must be the lower than the last?

Comment: first element must be the smallest in the sub sequence and last element must be biggest in sub sequence.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58430/discussion-between-wannabecoder-and-padraic-cunningham).

Answer (score 0):

get all subsequences where the first element `ele[0]` is the `minimum` and the last element `ele[-1]` is the `max`

```
values = [3,1,2,5,5]

def conseq_sequences(li):
    seq = []
    for i in range(len(li) + 1):
        seq += ([ele for ele in zip(*(li[i:] for i in range(i))) if ele[0] == min(ele) and ele[-1] == max(ele)])
    return len(filter(None, seq)) # remove []

In [5]:  conseq_sequences(values)
Out[5]: 11
```

We use + 1 to include the full list in case if we had values like  `[1,3,1,2,5,5]`.

```
for i in range(len(li) + 1):
```

Then we go through each possible subsequence filtering out elements that don't match our condition.

```
seq += ([ele for ele in zip(*(li[i:] for i in range(i))) if ele[0] == min(ele) and ele[-1] == max(ele)])
```

Finally we return the len of the list filtering any empty lists []:

```
(filter(None, seq)) = [(3,), (1,), (2,), (5,), (5,), (1, 2), (2, 5), (5, 5), (1, 2, 5), (2, 5, 5), (1, 2, 5, 5)]
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the problems given on the site HackerRank.com is to count the number of almost sorted intervals in a permutation of N numbers whose values range from 1 to N.

An interval of an array is defined as any contiguous non empty subset of numbers. For example, if the array is defined as { 3, 4, 1, 5, 2 } then valid intervals would include { 5 }, { 1, 5 }, { 3, 4, 1}.

An almost sorted interval of an array is any interval as described above plus the requirement that the first number is less then or equal to all other numbers in the interval and the last number is greater then or equal to all other numbers.

Using the array from above, the set of almost sorted intervals would include { 3, 4 }, {1, 5}, { 5 } but would not include { 5, 2 }.

So the entire set of almost sorted intervals would be { { 3 }, { 3, 4 }, { 4 }, { 1 }, { 1, 5 }, { 5 }, { 2 } }. The number of almost sorted intervals is therefore 7.

To meet the challenge, your solution must solve the problem in O(n * log n) time.

An O(n * n) solution is rather trivial. The O(n * log n) takes more effort.

I found the problem quite difficult with my original O(n * log n) being quite messy and felt there was a better way. Searching the web really didn't help much except for some folks giving some terrible hints that really didn't help much. When I finally peeked at the "editorial" section of HackerRank, the description of a more elegant solution was hard to read. After some effort, I finally came to understand how the solution works.

Define two arrays to help solve the problem of finding all almost sorted intervals in an array: left[i] = j where j < i and j is closest to i and a[j] > a[i] right[i] = j where j > i and j is closest to i and a[j] < a[i]

These arrays help define when two indices i and j make up an almost sorted interval. For some i and j, a[i] ... a[j] is an almost sorted interval if j < right[i] and i < left[j].

For the array a[] = { 3, 4, 1, 5, 2 }, left[] = { -1, -1, 2, -1, 3 } and right[] = { 2, 2, 5, 4, 5 }. Note that we use -1 for the left array to express the out of bounds position to the left and the value 5 (i.e. N) to express the out of bounds position to the right.

Looking at our arrays, we see that 3 < right[2] and 2 > left[3] which means that the interval { a[2], a[3] } (i.e. { 1 , 5 } ) is an almost sorted interval.

One interesting thing to note is that once we have defined left[] and right[] we have "encoded" the numbers and there relationship to each other allowing us now to solve the problem only dealing with the indices of the arrays and no longer the numbers that make up the array.

The left[] and right[] arrays can both be computed in O(n) time.

We can then use these arrays to efficiently count the total number of almost sorted intervals. We iterate from right to left across the indices. While we iterate over the array, we can keep a set B made up of all possible end indices for all intervals that start at or to the left of the current index.

This can be done by adding the index value i to the set B at index i and removing index value i at index left[i] (which will always be some index to the left of i). Maintaining the set B can be done in O(1) time.

For each index, we can then check how many indices in the B set would be a valid end index if the current index is the start index.

At index i, an index j would be in the B set only if i > left[j]. The interval { a[i] ... a[j] } is an almost sorted interval if j < right[i]. We can count how many indices in the set B are less then right[i] to know how many almost sorted intervals index position i contributes to the total number of almost sorted intervals (as a left index position of the interval). If we then accumulate these values across all indices we can find the total number of almost sorted intervals.

This only leaves how we can count the number of indices in B which are less then right[i] efficiently. This can be done using the Binary Index tree in O(log n) time.

Thus the total runtime will be O(n * log n).